create a dataset in sqllab query editor with parameters in Apache Superset
I'm new to Apache Superset and trying to create a dataset in sqllab query editor  with parameters similar to the query below
select * from employee_details where employee_id = {{ employee_id }}

and passing parameter like {"employee_id":3 }
I can run the query without any issue but unable to save the query as a dataset

error from docker log :
superset. exceptions.SupersetGenericDBErrorException: syntax error at or near "{"
2024-06-11 12:18:51 superset_app          | LINE 1: ...ELECT * FROM employee_details WHERE employee_id = {{ employe...
2024-06-11 12:18:51 superset_app          |
actual requirement create a user report chart based on userid as input parameter(dynamically)

You can't this way. Make a select without the jinja parameter. select * from employee_details. Save it as dataset. Then go to edit the dataset and in the SQL paste the sql with jinja:select * from employee_details where employee_id = {{ employee_id }}
Don't forget that the filter name in the dashboard that you will create must have the same name as your variable (employee_id)

This does not work, sql field is readonly in dataset edit form.
